# Microsoft Teams Messaging Extension query result invoke issue

Tags: typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating an app that shows results in the Teams command bar from the Microsoft Graph and displays them to a user. When the user then clicks on a result I want to display an adaptive card with more specific data on the chosen result. I am using `preview.content.tap` in order to trigger the `onSelectItem` function to get the adaptive card for the chosen result, which works well. The issue I am facing is when I want to clear the selected item from the command bar (clicking the "X" of the viewed result), I would expect to see the results of my previous search, but instead I get "We didn't find any matches"

Is there anything I can do to retain the results (e.g. a callback function, cache), or possibly restart the search without further input from the user?

[1. The list of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T4u2.png)

[2. The "X" in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4AN4.png)

[3. The result of clicking "X"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QKnw.png)

My code is as follows:

```
@PreventIframe("/myMessageExtension/config.html")
export default class MyMessageExtension implements IMessagingExtensionMiddlewareProcessor {

    public async onQuery(context: TurnContext, query: MessagingExtensionQuery): Promise<MessagingExtensionResult> {

        const results = await getGraphSearchResults(query);

        const attachments = results?.map((result: any) => {
            const name = result.resource.name ?? result.resource.fields?.title;
            const preview = CardFactory.heroCard(name, result.resource.fields.url);
            preview.content.tap = { type: 'invoke', value: { type: "SearchResult", result } };
            return preview;
        });

        return Promise.resolve({
            type: "result",
            attachmentLayout: "list",
            attachments
        } as MessagingExtensionResult);

    }

    public async onSelectItem(context: TurnContext, value: { type: string, result: any }): Promise<MessagingExtensionResult> {
        if (value.type === "SearchResult") {
            const attachment = await getAdaptiveCard(value.result);

            return Promise.resolve({
                type: "result",
                attachmentLayout: "list",
                attachments: [attachment]
            } as MessagingExtensionResult);
        }

        return Promise.resolve({
            type: "result",
            attachmentLayout: "list",
            attachments: []
        } as MessagingExtensionResult);
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Beier22 - If you set initialRun to true in your manifest you receive the invoke message as soon as the search command is invoked. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet#default-query) for more info.

Comment: Hi @Mamatha-MSFT, thank you for the response, initialRun was already set to true in the manifest, and it runs the first time, but it does not run when I clear the result that was chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clear the selected item from the command bar (clicking the "X" of the viewed result) and getting "We didn't find any matches" is the expected behavior. In compose area it you will get result even when you clear the search query but currently in command bar it will not work. It is by design.